# Mixing dicts with non-series error when attempting json to csv with pandas, but only when the json is retrieved from url

Tags: python, json, pandas

Python 3.8.5 with Pandas 1.1.3

This code, to convert Python json dict list to csv, using pandas, works without issue:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json

data = [{"results": [{"type": "ID", "value": "1234", "normalized": "1234", "count": 1, "offsets": [{"start": 14, "end": 25}], "id_b": "10"}, {"type": "ID", "value": "5678", "normalized": "5678", "count": 1, "offsets": [{"start": 32, "end": 43}], "id_b": "11"}], "responseHeaders": {"Date": "Tue, 25 May 2021 14:41:28 GMT", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": "350", "Connection": "keep-alive", "Server": "openresty", "X-StuffAPI-ProcessedLanguage": "eng", "X-StuffAPI-Request-Id": "abcdef", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload", "X-StuffAPI-App-Id": "123456789", "X-StuffAPI-Concurrency": "1"}}]

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data)).to_csv('file.csv')
```

The value in the `data` variable above is pasted directly from the response of an API call to one of our services. The problem occurs when I attempt to do everything including the API call in one script. Let's first look at everything in the script that seems to be working fine:

```
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    import stuff.api
    
    def run(key, url):
        # Create an API instance
        api = API(user_key=key, service_url=url)
        # submit data from a text file to the API parser
        file1 = open("123.txt","r")
            text_data = file1.read()
            params = DocumentParameters()
            params["content"] = text_data
            file1.close()
            try:
                return api.data(params)
            except StuffAPIException as exception:
                print(exception)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        result = run('1234', 'https://192.168.0.125:8100/rest/')
        y = json.dumps(result)
        t = type(y)
        print(y)
        print(t)
```

The above `print(y)` statement will return the exact data which I've shown in the `data` variable in the first code block above. And the `print(t)` statement was for me to capture the return type to help me try and diagnose the issue - the result of that is `<class 'str'>`.

So now we add this right under the `print(t)` line (exactly as in the first code block):

`pd.read_json(json.dumps(result)).to_csv('file.csv')`

And I get this error:

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous
> ordering.

I have seen the many threads about this error, but none of them seem to pertain exactly to what's happening here.

With my limited experience thus far, I am guessing this issue may be due to the return type being `string`?  I'm not sure, but this troubleshooting step is just the first hurdle to overcome - I need to eventually be able to parse the data into separate columns of the csv file, but for now, I just need to get it into the csv file without errors.

I understand you won't be able to *fully* reproduce this without access to my server, but hoping that's not needed to figure this out.

Comment: You can load a list of dicts directly in `pandas`, no need to convert it to `json` first. What happens if you do `pd.DataFrame(result)`?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I get the same ValueError when trying to get a DataFrame.  However, `pd.Series(result)` does work.  That certainly gets me closer, but the problem is the entirety of the results is returned as one long string value for index 0 of the series.  So the entire results set ends up in one cell in the csv file.  I have to get the values of the different keys into their own columns/rows.  But maybe that's a different problem for a different post.

Comment: Ah I see, `data` is a list with just a single dict in it. Does this work: `pd.DataFrame(data[0]['results'])`?

Comment: Nope -> `KeyError: 0`

Comment: have you tried removing json.dump() and just using json.loads()? you can try eval(result) or json.loads(eval(result)). It is tricky to help... I took your data above and made it a string and just used json.loads(data) and it seems to work.